# How to restart the minio server inside the docker container?

Tags: docker, minio

I have installed `minio` server inside the docker container. And then I have configured `amqp` in

```
vi ~/.minio/config.json.
```

Now I need to restart the `minio` server to apply the changes. I can restart docker container but the `minio` configuration changes are not reflected.

Kindly guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Need more clarifications to answer the question. Were you running `vi ~/.minio/config.json` inside the container? Did you save the file before you exited vi? After the edit, did you confirm the changes were in the config.json file by running `cat ~/.minio/config.json`?

Comment: I have saved the details config.json via basic linux commands. To reflect the changes I need to restart the minio service. I looking help on to restart the minio service.

Comment: Are you editing config.json inside the container or outside it?